# datatables not rendering the results

Tags: javascript, datatables, promise

I am using the datatables plugin to render some results, the complexity here is that I have to loop through some lists in Sharepoint, then make a query, and then append each result into a final result, and then show that final result.

When I debug the foreach(result), I can see that the results are appended, and I get 13 result items so far.

However when the debugger reaches the datatable.add method, then the array is empty, and nothing is rendered.

```
function GetData(billCycleId, clientCode, jobCodes, engagementCode) {
                    var enhanceFunctions = [
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddHyperLinkOnFields(searchResultRow, config.HyperLinks);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddPresenceOnFields(searchResultRow, config.UserFields);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.FormatDateFields(searchResultRow, config.DateFields, generalConfig.DateTimeFormat);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddImageMapping(searchResultRow, config.ImageFields);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.FormatNumberFields(searchResultRow, config.NumberFields);
                        }
                    ];

                    var selectProperties = spService.TransformFieldsToSelectProperties(config.Fields); 
                    var extendedSelectProperties = selectProperties.slice(); // copy array
                    var hyperLinkedProperties = spService.TransformFieldsToSelectProperties(config.HyperLinks)
                    extendedSelectProperties = extendedSelectProperties.concat(hyperLinkedProperties);

                    spService.GetAllListsFromWeb()
                        .then(function(lists){
                            var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
                            var result =[];
                            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                                var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
                                var title = oList.get_title();
                                var id = oList.get_id();
                                if(title.indexOf("Bill Cycles") !== -1){
                                    // Get data from SP
                                    GetRelatedBillCyclesFromList(id, extendedSelectProperties, billCycleId, clientCode, jobCodes, engagementCode, enhanceFunctions)
                                    .then(function (data) {
                                        var trimmedData = spService.SpSearchQuery.TrimSearchResultsToSelectProperties(data, selectProperties);                          
                                        // Add data to dataTable

                                        trimmedData.forEach(function(item){ // loop over source array
                                            result.push(item); //append to result array
                                        });
                                    })
                                    .catch (function (message) {
                                        vm.Name = "Error";
                                        vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;
                                    });
                                }
                                //Do something with oList.
                            }

                            var dataTable = $(tableSelector).DataTable();
                            dataTable.clear().rows.add(result).columns.adjust().draw(); // Resize columns based on new data sizes                                                       
                            vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;

                        })

                }


    function getAllListsFromWeb(){  
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var web = context.get_web();
                        var lists = web.get_lists();                          
                        context.load(lists);
                        context.executeQueryAsync(
                           function() {
                                $log.info("Successfully retrieved list item result");                          
                                deferred.resolve(lists);
                           },
                           function(error, errorInfo) {
                                $log.warn("Retrieving list item result failed");

                                deferred.reject(errorInfo);
                           }
                        );
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
```

Update 1

Also tried this but didnt work

```
function GetData(billCycleId, clientCode, jobCodes, engagementCode) {
                    var enhanceFunctions = [
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddHyperLinkOnFields(searchResultRow, config.HyperLinks);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddPresenceOnFields(searchResultRow, config.UserFields);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.FormatDateFields(searchResultRow, config.DateFields, generalConfig.DateTimeFormat);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.AddImageMapping(searchResultRow, config.ImageFields);
                        },
                        function(searchResultRow) {
                            return spService.FormatNumberFields(searchResultRow, config.NumberFields);
                        }
                    ];

                    var selectProperties = spService.TransformFieldsToSelectProperties(config.Fields); 
                    var extendedSelectProperties = selectProperties.slice(); // copy array
                    var hyperLinkedProperties = spService.TransformFieldsToSelectProperties(config.HyperLinks)
                    extendedSelectProperties = extendedSelectProperties.concat(hyperLinkedProperties);

                    var result =[];

                    var data = spService.GetAllListsFromWeb()
                        .then(function(lists){
                            var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
                            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                                var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
                                var title = oList.get_title();
                                var id = oList.get_id();
                                if(title.indexOf("Bill Cycles") !== -1){
                                    // Get data from SP
                                    GetRelatedBillCyclesFromList(id, extendedSelectProperties, billCycleId, clientCode, jobCodes, engagementCode, enhanceFunctions)
                                    .then(function (data) {
                                        var trimmedData = spService.SpSearchQuery.TrimSearchResultsToSelectProperties(data, selectProperties);                          
                                        // Add data to dataTable

                                        trimmedData.forEach(function(item){ // loop over source array
                                            result.push(item); //append to result array
                                        });
                                    })
                                    .catch (function (message) {
                                        vm.Name = "Error";
                                        vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            return result;
                        })

                        var resultadata = data;
                        var dataTable = $(tableSelector).DataTable();
                        dataTable.clear().rows.add(resultdata).columns.adjust().draw(); // Resize columns based on new data sizes              
                        vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data seems to be a promise you could try this:

```
//not saving it to data
spService.GetAllListsFromWeb()
.then(function (lists) {
  var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
  return Promise.all(
    (function(){
      var promises = [];
      while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var title = oList.get_title();
        var id = oList.get_id();
        if (title.indexOf("Bill Cycles") !== -1) {
          // Get data from SP !!! this is also async and returns a promise
          //   add the promise to promises array and wait for all to finish
          //   look above in Promise.all
          promises.push(
            GetRelatedBillCyclesFromList(
              id, 
              extendedSelectProperties, 
              billCycleId, 
              clientCode, 
              jobCodes, 
              engagementCode, 
              enhanceFunctions
            )
            .then(function (data) {
              return spService
              .SpSearchQuery
              .TrimSearchResultsToSelectProperties(
                data, 
                selectProperties
              );
            })
          );
        }
      }
      return promises
    })() //IIFE returning an array of promises
  );
})
.then(
  function(data){
    console.log("got data:",JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));
    var resultadata = data;
    var dataTable = $(tableSelector).DataTable();
    dataTable.clear().rows.add(resultdata).columns.adjust().draw(); // Resize columns based on new data sizes              
    vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;    
  }
);
```

You should really check out what a promise is and how it's used in JavaScript.

Since functions you write are always synchronous (only one thread running your code) your functions need to return a value immediately (non blocking).

When a function needs to make a network request, file IO or long running process you immediately return a promise. A promise is an object that has a function called `then` that takes 2 handler functions

1. Resolve handler: This is called when the promise resolves (network request finished and value is returned). The handler is passed one argument which is the resolve value (for network request this would be the response).
2. Reject handler: This is called when the promise rejects. For example the url for a request is invalid or server is down. The parameter to this function is the error.

So when you try to do stuff like:

```
var result = [];
var later = x => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r(x),100));
[1,2,3,4,5]
.map(
  x => 
    later(x)
    .then(
      x => {
        console.log("resolved with:",x);
        result.push(x);
        return x;
      }
    )
);
console.log("first output",result);

//the output will be:
// first output []
// resolved with: 1
// resolved with: 2
// resolved with: 3
// resolved with: 4
// resolved with: 5
```

You will see that by the time you try to do something with result none of the promises are resolved so it's empty. In the answer I put here I use `Promise.all` to resolve all promises and then use the resolve values for the dataTable.

Comment: it doesnt work, still get nothing, the second piece seems to be executed first

Comment: @LuisValencia Yes, sorry. Lot of code there and I missed one promise returning function. so updated the answer

Comment: amazing explanation, testing it

Comment: mmm, I get a resulting array of 12 undefined items, we're close

Comment: when debugging I noticed that at somepoint trimmedData actually has an array of 12 items with the desired result values, I guess its lost in the next while iteration.  shouldnt I build an array like I was doing it before? trimmedData.forEach(function(item){ // loop over source array
           result.push(item); //append to result array
          });, no idea how to return that array t o the promise?

Comment: its working now! just added the push foreach and used that variable to render the datatable

Comment: @LuisValencia I updated the answer, forgot to return the result after trimming data, normally I don't write block functions `function(x){...return}` but arrow without block: `x=>somevalue` where somevalue is automatically returned because it's only one statement. Not sure if you need to flatten the data: `[ [ 1 ,2 ] , [3,4] ]` to `[1,2,3,4]` if you do I can show you how to do that with simple `Array.prototype.reduce`